# Not able to use SelectedRows in Salesforce Lightning DataTable

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am using Salesforce Lightning data table to show records on a lightning component and if we select any record and then we search any record using server side calling then the previously selected record was removed from the selected rows list.
I am using "SelectedRows" attribute and passing the list of id of all selected rows in it.
Please suggest if anyone has any inputs on this.

Comment: You should [edit] your post to give a reproducible code sample for this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to specify "key-field" ? Could you share your code so we can help you debug ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to build my own handleSelect to work:

```
    handleSelect : function(component, event, helper) {              
    var selectedRows = event.getParam('selectedRows');        
    var currentSelectedRows = component.get("v.selectedRows");

     for ( var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++ ) {                        
        currentSelectedRows.push(selectedRows[i].Id);
     }   

    component.set("v.selectedRows", currentSelectedRows);        
},
```

---

```
<lightning:datatable keyField="Id" data="{! v.lineItemBulkList }" columns="{! v.lineItemColumns }" selectedRows="{! v.selectedRows }" hideCheckboxColumn="false" onrowselection="{!c.handleSelect}"/>
```